# Error al trabajar con transacciones en c# con procedimientos almacenados

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework, stored-procedure, transact-sql

tengo el siguiente inconveniente al momento que estoy insertando registros en mi procedimiento almacenado, estoy trabajando con transacciones por lo cual, al insertar un registro, hago el `COMMIT` de la transacción, por lo cual si me falla insertando el 3 registro lo que debería hacer es un `ROLLBACK` a la transaccion, ya que dio error, pero no sé cómo trabajaría esta parte en .NET CORE,

este es mi código,

Codigo SQL tablas,

```
CREATE TABLE PharmacyMovements(
PharmacyMovementId CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
PharmacyAddressId INT NOT NULL,
PharmacyMovementDate DATE NOT NULL,
RepresentativeId INT NOT NULL,
PhotoPath VARCHAR(250) NULL,
CompanyId INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PharmacyMovements_PharmacyMovementId PRIMARY KEY (PharmacyMovementId)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE PharmacyMovementDetails(
PharmacyMovementDetailId CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
PharmacyMovementId CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
ArticleId INT NOT NULL,
Quantity INT NOT NULL,
CompanyId INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PharmacyMovementDetails_PharmacyMovementDetailId PRIMARY KEY (PharmacyMovementDetailId)
)
GO
```

Codigo de procedimiento almacenado encabezado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PharmacyMovementSave
(
     @PharmacyMovementId CHAR(16)
    ,@PharmacyAddressId INT
    ,@PharmacyMovementDate DATE
    ,@RepresentativeId INT
    ,@PhotoPath VARCHAR(250)
    ,@CompanyId INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TRANCOUNT INT;
    SET @TRANCOUNT = @@TRANCOUNT;
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        ELSE
            SAVE TRANSACTION PharmacyMovementSave;
                
                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PharmacyMovements WHERE PharmacyMovementId = @PharmacyMovementId)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra en el sistema, el registro que desea agregar', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END

                INSERT INTO PharmacyMovements
                    (
                      PharmacyMovementId
                     ,PharmacyAddressId
                     ,PharmacyMovementDate
                     ,RepresentativeId
                     ,PhotoPath
                     ,CompanyId
                    )
                VALUES (
                      @PharmacyMovementId
                     ,@PharmacyAddressId
                     ,@PharmacyMovementDate
                     ,@RepresentativeId
                     ,@PhotoPath
                     ,@CompanyId
                    );

        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0   
            COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER INT, @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000), @XACT_STATE INT;
        SELECT @ERRORNUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER(), @MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @XACT_STATE = XACT_STATE();
        IF @XACT_STATE = -1
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT = 0
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION PharmacyMovementSave;

        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, 16, 1) ;
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Codigo procedimiento almacenado detalle,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PharmacyMovementDetailSave
(
     @PharmacyMovementDetailId CHAR(16)
    ,@PharmacyMovementId CHAR(16)
    ,@ArticleId INT
    ,@Quantity INT
    ,@CompanyId INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TRANCOUNT INT;
    SET @TRANCOUNT = @@TRANCOUNT;
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        ELSE
            SAVE TRANSACTION PharmacyMovementDetailSave;
                
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PharmacyMovements WHERE PharmacyMovementId = @PharmacyMovementId)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('No se encuentra en el sistema, el registro que desea agregar', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END

                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PharmacyMovementDetails WHERE PharmacyMovementDetailId = @PharmacyMovementDetailId)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra en el sistema, el registro que desea agregar', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END

                INSERT INTO PharmacyMovementDetails
                    (
                      PharmacyMovementDetailId
                     ,PharmacyMovementId
                     ,ArticleId
                     ,Quantity
                     ,CompanyId
                     ,CreateBy
                     ,CreationDate
                     ,ModifiedBy
                     ,ModifiedDate
                    )
                VALUES (
                      @PharmacyMovementDetailId
                     ,@PharmacyMovementId
                     ,@ArticleId
                     ,@Quantity
                     ,@CompanyId
                    );

        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0   
            COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER INT, @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000), @XACT_STATE INT;
        SELECT @ERRORNUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER(), @MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @XACT_STATE = XACT_STATE();
        IF @XACT_STATE = -1
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT = 0
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION PharmacyMovementDetailSave;

        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, 16, 1) ;
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente, tengo un encabezado y un detalle, luego de que inserte el encabezado, procedo a recorrer un `FOREACH` para ir insertando el detalle, pero si falla, deseo darle un ROLLBACK, a la transaccion completa, en esta es la parte que necesito ayuda,

Estoy usando repository pattern c# with entity framework core,

Quedó a la espera de sus comentarios

Comment: No termino de entender que tiene que ver EF con los SP... es mas.. no entiendo, si los SP ya tienen el codigo de rollback, donde es que esta el error?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que pasa es que los SP tienen codigo rollback, pero en caso de que sea un proceso que agregue varias inserciones o actualizaciones, eso es lo que quiero saber, por ejemplo un encabezado y un detalle, hasta que no este completo, no puedo dar la transaccion por valida, no se si me doy a entender

Comment: no, yo por lo menos no termino de entender. Cuando tenes una cabecera e items, envolves todo en una transaccion, y hasta que no ingresa la cabecera y todos los items no haces el commit... por lo que veo, vos tenes en cada caso el commit y el rollback.. tu pregunta es si podes tener una transaccion superios? creo que si, depende tu base de datos... si no, vas a tener que cambiar esos SP para que no hagan el commit, y otro procedimiento sea el que llame a estos dos... Lo que no entiendo, es por ejemplo que tiene que ver EF con tu pregunta.. o asp.net...

Comment: @gbianchi te comento, de la forma en la que estan creados los SP esta bien, lo que quiero saber en los casos que es un solo objeto me funciona bien, pero en el caso de un encabezado de una factura la inserto con mi SP, que tiene el comit, y en el detalle por igual, lo que quiero saber es si en EF puedo tener una trasaccion superior que me controle ese lote de registros que voy a insertar y si hay algun error hacer un rollback a toda la transaccion, pero desde EF

Comment: ok.. perfecto.. eso deberia estar claro en tu pregunta.. yo no tengo idea, supondria que deberias poder... perooooo... no lo se realmetne.... Igual, todo el codigo de los SP es superfluo (no tenes problemas ahi, y yo me pase un buen rato buscandoles problemas), como asi tambien los create.. enfoca tu pregunta al problema real (podes poner una version cortisima del SP como ejemplo)...

Comment: llegaste a la solución del problema?

Comment: @JeffersonCuji no he llegado la solución del problema, pero te comento lo stored procedure estan bien, pero lo que necesito saber es como hago una transacción desde EF, que me contenga una cabera y varios detalles, ejemplo si inserto la cabecera y me fallo algo en el detalle tengo que devolver la transacción y en caso de que no ocurra nada, tengo que dar la trasaccion por completá y no se como plantearlo porque no manejo muy bien EF, ya que desde hay llamo los SP, espero tus comentarios

Comment: Si necesitas invocar en bucle a ese SP para insertar el detalle, el SP no debe manejar la transaccion porque una vez que haces el commit de 1 registro ya no lo puedes deshacer. Existen dos alternativas principalmente, uno es que el SP reciba un parametro de tipo tabla y .net se lo enviaria en forma de datatabla (requiere SQL Server 2012 en adelante para esto), la otra es que en tu aplicación .net abras una conexión con  una transaccion, tengas el bucle de los inserts y cuando termina el bucle realizas el commit (en este caso eliminando las transas del SP)

Comment: Buenas, yo lo quw hago es dejar el sp sin commit adentro y lo maneja la transacción que lo llame por fuera. Si el sp falla, tira error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjunto un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo, primero partiendo del uso de una biblioteca de clases para aplicar el patrón repositorio que mencionas y la organización el proyecto en general.

> **1**. **ENTIDADES**

***PharmacyMovement***

```
[Table("PharmacyMovement", Schema = "dbo")]
public class PharmacyMovement
{
    [Key]
    public string PharmacyMovementId { get; set; }
    public int PharmacyAddressId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PharmacyMovementDate { get; set; }
    public int RepresentativeId { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

***PharmacyMovementDetail***

```
[Table("PharmacyMovementDetail", Schema = "dbo")]
public class PharmacyMovementDetail
{
    [Key]
    public string PharmacyMovementDetailId { get; set; }
    public string PharmacyMovementId { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

> **2. CONTEXTO DE BASE DE DATOS Y ENTIDADES DEL MISMO**

```
public class ContextDB:DbContext
{
    public ContextDB(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
    public DbSet<PharmacyMovement> PharmacyMovements { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PharmacyMovementDetail> PharmacyMovementDetails { get; set; }
}
```

> **3. DTO Y ASIGNACIÓN DE OBJETOS**

***PharmacyMovementDTO***

```
public class PharmacyMovementDTO
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mensaje")]
    public string PharmacyMovementId { get; set; }
    public int PharmacyAddressId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PharmacyMovementDate { get; set; }
    public int RepresentativeId { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

***PharmacyMovementDetailDTO***

```
public class PharmacyMovementDetailDTO
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mensaje")]
    public string PharmacyMovementDetailId { get; set; }
    public string PharmacyMovementId { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

***PharmacyTransaction para manejar las dos entidades que se envía al método del controlador***

```
public class PharmacyTransaction
{
    public PharmacyMovementDTO PharmacyMovementDTO { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetailDTO> PharmacyMovementDetailDTO { get; set; }
}
```

***MapperConfig mapeo entre clases para facilitar la asignación de objeto a objeto. Con la librería AutoMapper se evita hacerlo manualmente***

```
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<PharmacyMovementDTO, PharmacyMovement>();
            cfg.CreateMap<PharmacyMovement, PharmacyMovementDTO>();

            cfg.CreateMap<PharmacyMovementDetailDTO, PharmacyMovementDetail>();
            cfg.CreateMap<PharmacyMovementDetail, PharmacyMovementDetailDTO>();

        });
    }
}
```

> **4. REPOSITORIOS**

***Interface para el repositorio genérico que maneja el CRUD***

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    //métodos...
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

***Interface para el repositorio PharmacyMovement***

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementRepository : IGenericRepository<PharmacyMovement> { }
```

***Interface para el repositorio PharmacyMovementDetail***

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository : IGenericRepository<PharmacyMovementDetail>
{
    void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

> **5. IMPLEMENTACIÓN DE LOS REPOSITORIOS**

***Implementación genérica***

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public GenericRepository() { }
    
    //métodos...

    public TEntity Insert(TEntity entity, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

***Implementación del repositorio PharmacyMovement***

```
public class TPharmacyMovementRepository : GenericRepository<PharmacyMovement>, IPharmacyMovementRepository { }
```

***Implementación del repositorio PharmacyMovementDetail***

```
public class TPharmacyMovementDetailRepository : GenericRepository<PharmacyMovementDetail>, IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository
{
    public void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        var listDetalle = detalle.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < listDetalle.Count(); i++)
        {
            listDetalle[i].PharmacyMovementId = pharmacyMovementId;
            dbContext.PharmacyMovementDetails.Add(listDetalle[i]);
        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

> **6. SERVICIOS**

***Interface para el servicio genérico***

```
public interface IGenericService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    //métodos...
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

***Interface para el servicio PharmacyMovement***

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementService : IGenericService<PharmacyMovement> { }
```

***Interface para el servicio PharmacyMovementDetail***

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementDetailService : IGenericService<PharmacyMovementDetail>
{
    void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

> **7. IMPLEMENTACIÓN DE LOS SERVICIOS**

***Implementación del servicio genérico***

```
public class GenericService<TEntity> : IGenericService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private IGenericRepository<TEntity> genericRepository;
    public GenericService(IGenericRepository<TEntity> genericRepository)
    {
        this.genericRepository = genericRepository;
    }
    public TEntity Insert(TEntity entity, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        return genericRepository.Insert(entity, dbContext);
    }
}
```

***Implementación del servicio PharmacyMovement***

```
public class PharmacyMovementService : GenericService<PharmacyMovement>, IPharmacyMovementService
{
    public PharmacyMovementService(IPharmacyMovementRepository pharmacyMovementRepository) : base(pharmacyMovementRepository) { }
}
```

***Implementación del servicio PharmacyMovementDetail***

```
public class PharmacyMovementDetailService : GenericService<PharmacyMovementDetail>, IPharmacyMovementDetailService
{
    private readonly IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository pharmacyMovementDetailRepository;
    public PharmacyMovementDetailService(IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository pharmacyMovementDetailRepository) : base(pharmacyMovementDetailRepository)
    {
        this.pharmacyMovementDetailRepository = pharmacyMovementDetailRepository;
    }
    public void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        pharmacyMovementDetailRepository.Registrar(detalle, pharmacyMovementId, dbContext);
    }
}
```

> **8. PROYECTO ASP.NET CORE API**

***Cadena de conexión sql en la configuración del archivo json***

```
"ConnectionString": {
    "connectionString":"Server=DESKTOP7MFLKJF\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbDemo;Integrated Security=True"
 }
```

***Clase para manejar la cadena de conexión sql***

```
public class SqlHelper
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

***Configuración de AutoMapper y cadena de conexión en la clase Startup***

```
public class Startup
{
    internal static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; set; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        Action<SqlHelper> connectionSql = (opt =>
        {
            opt.ConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionString:connectionString"];
        });
        services.Configure(connectionSql);
        services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SqlHelper>>().Value);
    }
}
```

***Controlador con el método para el ingreso de PharmacyMovement y PharmacyMovementDetail usando una transacción***

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DemoController : ControllerBase
{
    private IMapper mapper;
    private PharmacyMovementDetailService pharmacyMovementDetailService = new PharmacyMovementDetailService(new TPharmacyMovementDetailRepository());
    private PharmacyMovementService pharmacyMovementService = new PharmacyMovementService(new TPharmacyMovementRepository());
    private static string connectionDB;
    public DemoController(SqlHelper sqlHelper)
    {
        mapper = Startup.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        connectionDB = sqlHelper.ConnectionString;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(PharmacyTransaction data)
    {
        TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
        options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
        {
            using (var db = new ContextDB(connectionDB))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Se mapea las entidades
                    var objPharmacyMovement = mapper.Map<PharmacyMovement>(data.PharmacyMovementDTO);
                    var listTPharmacyMovementDetail = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail>>(data.PharmacyMovementDetailDTO);

                    //Se inserta el objeto PharmacyMovement
                    pharmacyMovementService.Insert(objPharmacyMovement, db);

                    //Se inserta el objeto PharmacyMovementDetail
                    pharmacyMovementDetailService.Registrar(listTPharmacyMovementDetail, objPharmacyMovement.PharmacyMovementId, db);
                    
                    //Se realiza el commit
                    scope.Complete();
                    return Ok("success");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Se realiza el rollback en caso de generarse algún error
                    scope.Dispose();
                    return BadRequest("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usando postman se realiza el envío de los datos siguiendo la estructura de la clase PharmacyTransaction a la [UrlLocalHost](https://localhost:44332/api/Demo)

```
{
  "PharmacyMovementDTO": {
    "PharmacyMovementId": "A",
    "PharmacyAddressId": 2,
    "PharmacyMovementDate": "2022-04-13T08:47:27.3715214-05:00",
    "RepresentativeId": 3,
    "PhotoPath": "urlFoto",
    "CompanyId": 4
},
  "PharmacyMovementDetailDTO": [
  {
    "PharmacyMovementDetailId": "Y",
    "PharmacyMovementId": "A",
    "ArticleId": 2,
    "Quantity": 3,
    "CompanyId": 4
  },
  {
    "PharmacyMovementDetailId": "Z",
    "PharmacyMovementId": "A",
    "ArticleId": 2,
    "Quantity": 3,
    "CompanyId": 4
  }
 ]
}
```

El ejemplo no es algo absoluto a seguir pero te puede servir para guiarte y profundizar el tema.

Si deseas descargar el proyecto: [Enlace](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MyxzlQlnyijbszLnavYfz1w5NCM_kCLH?usp=sharing)

***ACTUALIZACIÓN***

Para usar los SP tendrías que llamarlos añadiendo el método en la implementación de cada repositorio:

**Interface para el repositorio PharmacyMovement**

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementRepository : IGenericRepository<PharmacyMovement> 
{
    void RegistrarSp(PharmacyMovement pharmacyMovement, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

**Interface para el repositorio PharmacyMovementDetail**

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository : IGenericRepository<PharmacyMovementDetail>
{
    void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext);
    void RegistrarSp(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

**Implementación del repositorio PharmacyMovement**

```
public class TPharmacyMovementRepository : GenericRepository<PharmacyMovement>, IPharmacyMovementRepository 
{
    public void RegistrarSp(PharmacyMovement pharmacyMovement, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "PharmacyMovementSave";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PharmacyMovementId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = pharmacyMovement.PharmacyMovementId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PharmacyAddressId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pharmacyMovement.PharmacyAddressId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PharmacyMovementDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = pharmacyMovement.PharmacyMovementDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RepresentativeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pharmacyMovement.RepresentativeId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoPath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pharmacyMovement.PhotoPath;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pharmacyMovement.CompanyId;
        cmd.Connection = (SqlConnection)dbContext.Database.Connection;
        dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**Implementación del repositorio PharmacyMovementDetail**

```
public class TPharmacyMovementDetailRepository : GenericRepository<PharmacyMovementDetail>, IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository
{
    public void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        var listDetalle = detalle.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < listDetalle.Count(); i++)
        {
            listDetalle[i].PharmacyMovementId = pharmacyMovementId;
            dbContext.PharmacyMovementDetails.Add(listDetalle[i]);
        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void RegistrarSp(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        var listDetalle = detalle.ToList();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "PharmacyMovementDetailSave";
        for (int i = 0; i < listDetalle.Count(); i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PharmacyMovementDetailId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = listDetalle[i].PharmacyMovementDetailId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PharmacyMovementId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = pharmacyMovementId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArticleId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = listDetalle[i].ArticleId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = listDetalle[i].Quantity;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = listDetalle[i].CompanyId;
            cmd.Connection = (SqlConnection)dbContext.Database.Connection;
            dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface para el servicio PharmacyMovement**

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementService : IGenericService<PharmacyMovement> 
{
    void RegistrarSp(PharmacyMovement pharmacyMovement, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

**Interface para el servicio PharmacyMovementDetail**

```
public interface IPharmacyMovementDetailService : IGenericService<PharmacyMovementDetail>
{
    void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext);
    void RegistrarSp(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext);
}
```

**Implementación del servicio PharmacyMovement**

```
public class PharmacyMovementService : GenericService<PharmacyMovement>, IPharmacyMovementService
{
    private readonly IPharmacyMovementRepository pharmacyMovementRepository;
    public PharmacyMovementService(IPharmacyMovementRepository pharmacyMovementRepository) : base(pharmacyMovementRepository) 
    {
        this.pharmacyMovementRepository = pharmacyMovementRepository;
    }
    public void RegistrarSp(PharmacyMovement pharmacyMovement, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        pharmacyMovementRepository.RegistrarSp(pharmacyMovement, dbContext);
    }
}
```

**Implementación del servicio PharmacyMovementDetail**

```
public class PharmacyMovementDetailService : GenericService<PharmacyMovementDetail>, IPharmacyMovementDetailService
{
    private readonly IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository pharmacyMovementDetailRepository;
    public PharmacyMovementDetailService(IPharmacyMovementDetailRepository pharmacyMovementDetailRepository) : base(pharmacyMovementDetailRepository)
    {
        this.pharmacyMovementDetailRepository = pharmacyMovementDetailRepository;
    }
    public void Registrar(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        pharmacyMovementDetailRepository.Registrar(detalle, pharmacyMovementId, dbContext);
    }
    public void RegistrarSp(IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail> detalle, string pharmacyMovementId, ContextDB dbContext)
    {
        pharmacyMovementDetailRepository.RegistrarSp(detalle, pharmacyMovementId, dbContext);
    }
}
```

**Y en el controlador apuntas a los métodos que usan el SP**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(PharmacyTransaction data)
    {
        TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
        options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
        {
            using (var db = new ContextDB(connectionDB))
            {
                try
                {
                    var objPharmacyMovement = mapper.Map<PharmacyMovement>(data.PharmacyMovementDTO);
                    var listTPharmacyMovementDetail = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PharmacyMovementDetail>>(data.PharmacyMovementDetailDTO);
                    pharmacyMovementService.RegistrarSp(objPharmacyMovement, db);
                    pharmacyMovementDetailService.RegistrarSp(listTPharmacyMovementDetail, objPharmacyMovement.PharmacyMovementId, db);
                    scope.Complete();
                    return Ok("success");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    scope.Dispose();
                    return BadRequest("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: veo la respuesta, excelente solo una inquietud, en el caso de agregar los objetos mefiante EF, llamos los SP, me funcionaran de la misma manera, tal y como los tengo, es decir EF, manejaria lo que es la trasacción padre y las internas en caso dd que fallen podria hacer un rollback

Comment: La pregunta es sobre SQL Server, en que momento pregunto sobre EntityFramework?????

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera si pero estarías manejando una transacción en EF y otra en SqlServer. Editaré la respuesta para adjuntar lo que mencionas.

Comment: De acuerdo, eso es lo que quiero ya que me falle en el detalle, simplemente la transacción de EF le doy un rollback y se quedaria como estaba

Answer (score 1):

Estimado yo lo hago en mis sistemas de una forma mucho mas simple, espero te sirva.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('PharmacyMovementSave') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     DROP PROCEDURE PharmacyMovementSave
     PRINT '<<< PROCEDIMIENTO DROPEADO PharmacyMovementSave >>>'
END
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE PharmacyMovementSave
(
     @PharmacyMovementId CHAR(16)
    ,@PharmacyAddressId INT
    ,@PharmacyMovementDate DATE
    ,@RepresentativeId INT
    ,@PhotoPath VARCHAR(250)
    ,@CompanyId INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRAN
    IF ((SELECT 1 FROM PharmacyMovements WHERE PharmacyMovementId = @PharmacyMovementId) = 1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El ID de movimiento ya se encuentra registrado en la tabla PharmacyMovements', 12, 1);
        RETURN(0);
    END

    INSERT INTO PharmacyMovements
            (
                PharmacyMovementId
                ,PharmacyAddressId
                ,PharmacyMovementDate
                ,RepresentativeId
                ,PhotoPath
                ,CompanyId
            )
        VALUES (
                @PharmacyMovementId
                ,@PharmacyAddressId
                ,@PharmacyMovementDate
                ,@RepresentativeId
                ,@PhotoPath
                ,@CompanyId
            );

    IF (@@error!=0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('PharmacyMovementSave: Cannot insert because primary key value found in PharmacyMovements', 12, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN(1)
    END
    COMMIT TRAN
END
GO


IF OBJECT_ID('PharmacyMovementSave') IS NOT NULL
     PRINT '<<< PROCEDIMIENTO PharmacyMovementSave CREADO >>>'
ELSE
     PRINT '<<< HA FALLADO LA CREACION DEL PROCEDIMIENTO PharmacyMovementSave >>>'
GO
```